crm 2016 Query Builder Error salesorderdetail customView
We are using M$-CRM 2016 onPremise 9.1 and having the following issue:
I have a lookup on the entity salesorderdetail and use addCustomView for a special filter. But I always getting the error mentioned in subject.
On deeper search I recognized why, and don't understand why crm this is doing that.
I opened the developer tools and network and saw a 400 bad Request. Detailed error:
'SalesOrderDetail' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'name'
But my fetchXml does not contain this attribute.
A closer look at this: this attribute is added by crm automatically.
I compared it with a customView for quotedetails, and saw that there is also added an attribute, but in this case:
<attribute name="quotedetailname"/>
and this is correct.
But on salesorderdetail it should be
<attribute name="salesorderdetailname"/>
Why does M$-CRM add this name-attribute to my fetchxml?
Can anyone reproduce this problem and has anybody a solution for it?
thx
©a-x-i

My bug was in this line of code:
formContext.getControl("wdps_base_salesorderdetail")).addCustomView(viewId, "product", "Basisprodukt", fetchXml, gridLayout, true);
I passed the wrong logicalName (second parameter). It shoud be "salesorderdetail" rather than "product". The strange thing is the behaviour of Dynamics CRM, because the error-message guides me to the wrong direction and I forgot to have a closer look at the code. The other strange thing was, that Dynamics CRM adds an fix parameter to the fetchxml, this is the main-attribute of the entity passed as second parameter. In my case attribute 'name' was the attribute of product.
thx for reading :)
